# How can I implement AirPrint using any mac-served printer using this "DNS-SD" configuration?

Tags: ipad, airprint

AirPrint is a function on iOS that allows you to print from your iPad (or whatever) to certain wireless printers.  Sadly, there are only a dozen or so compatible printers.

However, on the article on AirPrint on Wikipedia, the article states that it is possible to make the feature work with ANY printer that is connected to your mac. Specifically, the text says:

*"For other printers, AirPrint support can be added to an existing CUPS Server with DNS based Service Discovery, by manually adding DNS-SD printer service discovery records to a name server.[7]"*

The footnote takes a person to a very techie article about DNS stuff:  http://www.dns-sd.org/ServerStaticSetup.html ... but it is not written in a way an average power user could understand.

My question: **What is an only-moderately-techie set of instructions that will tell me how to configure this, using this method, so that I can have my iPad print wirelessly to an HP P1102w printer that is connected (via wifi, in fact) to my mac?**

Comment: Are you also looking for recommendations for DNS server setup on your network or do you already have a specific software stack running your own DNS? That's a lot of work to avoid the $20 license for AirPrint which just works and has a free trial so you don't have to buy until you're sure it works for you.

Comment: I assume you mean printopia as the $20 app you are mentioning, which will make airprint work for me?  That's the point that was made by an answerer below and both of you are totally right.  thx!

Comment: Yes. printopia by ecamm is thhe $20 AirPrint app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this isn't directly what you asked for, but if you are looking for a non-techie approach to sharing printers via Airprint, you could do far worse than to use [Printopia](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/printopia/).  It's not free, but it isn't expensive and it works very well indeed.

Comment: +1 I thought briefly the same thing when I first heard of airprint but quickly realized I can't compete with the $20 price - it's simply not worth my time setting up a local DNS server when I have fully functional demo software to try and then buy. It just works, and works very well.

Comment: Aha, great answer. thanks very much.  Funny, I had heard about printopia in my various surfing for answers, but I hadn't gotten the message that it was indeed the one that worked well, as opposed to sketchily.  I realized that one reason it was lower-profile in my research is because of its existence as something that runs on your mac, not as an app on the ipad (therefore I couldn't see reviews/stars on the ipad app store)  and furthermore, it's not for sale on the MAC app store so no reviews or stars there.  but, I have the info now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not "non" techie, but there's a more detailed explanation at

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2751128?start=0&tstart=0

(I intend to try this, but have not yet...)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Whilst your answer may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the article in an answer below, and provide the link for reference